# How to set input focus to a shown dialog in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

In a button click slot, I create and `exec()` a dialog with a NULL parent. Inside the dialog's constructor, I have:

```
this->activateWindow();
this->raise();
this->setFocus();
```

The dialog is application modal and has strong focus. However, it does NOT respond to keyboard events until I click on it. How do I make the dialog get focus without having to click it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I was setting the Qt:Tool window flag. Using Qt::Popup or Qt::Window instead will cause input focus is automatically set when the dialog is shown.

I used Qt::Window myself. Some of the other flags will probably work as well, but the main thing is that a QDialog with the Qt::Tool flag will **not** automatically set input focus when the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 0):

In my case even settings Qt::Window didn't do the trick. I had to

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(widgetToFocus, "setFocus", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

before `show()` or `exec()`.

Answer (score -1):

Install the Event filter for the dialog.

```
classObject->installEventFilter(this);

void className::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
   if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Space) 
    {
   focusNextChild();
    }
   else 
   {
  QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
   }
}
```

for more info refer here. 
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/eventsandfilters.html

Comment: The class is just a QDialog-derived class, with the following window flags set: `(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` It has no children and no parent.

Comment: ya, what ever, for dialog you want to get the keyboard events, install the event filter for dialog, in dialog constructor you write this->installEventFilter(this); igonre the function "focusNextChild()" in my sample above. 
in the dialog herder file declare keyPressEvent function and cpp file provide the implementation as above

Comment: So do you mean this?

    this->installEventFilter(this);

    void QDialogDerived::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
    {
        QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
        // do my processing here?
    }

Comment: ya there you check the key type based on the event, like Space or enter key.. etc...

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. See, the problem is, when the dialog is shown, it does not have input focus. *I can click on the dialog with the mouse and it gets input focus just fine.* I need to make the dialog *take input focus automatically* without having to click on it first.